# Reverse return value of callback with function - not(callback)

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I have a filtering function and i pass a testing function into it:

```
var array = [1,3,5,7,9]
function bigger(n){return n > 5}

function filterArray(data,testfn){
  return data.filter(e=> testfn(e))}

console.log(filterArray(array,bigger))
>>>[7,9]
```

now id like to be able to write

```
console.log(filterArray(array,not(bigger)))
>>>[1,3,5]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a function `not` that takes in a function and returns another function which returns the inverse of the result of calling the original function:

```js
var array = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];

function bigger(n) {
  return n > 5
}

function filterArray(data, testfn) {
  return data.filter(e => testfn(e))
}

function not(f) {
  return function(n) {
    return !f(n);
  }
}


console.log(filterArray(array, bigger));
console.log(filterArray(array, not(bigger)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
var array = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

const isBiggerThan = (n) => n > 5
const isNot = (fn) => (n) => !fn(n)
const filterArray = (data, testfn) => data.filter(e => testfn(e))    

console.log(filterArray(array, isBiggerThan))
console.log(filterArray(array, isNot(isBiggerThan)))
```

The idea is to have the `isNot` function return a function which simply negates the result of the passed as parameter function.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following.

```
var array = [1,3,5,7,9]
function bigger(n){return n > 5}

console.log(array.filter(element => !bigger(element)))
```

Comment: the point was to make it modular so i can exchange bigger with: larger,fewer,longer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To account for variadic functions:
Collecting arguments in an array "arguments" and passing them on to the function.

```
function not(myFunction){
  if (typeof myFunction != "function"){return !myFunction } 
   return function (...arguments) {
      return !myFunction.apply(null,arguments)
   }
 }
```

in short:

```
const not = f => (...a) => !f.apply(null,a)
```

Also to make it work for all values - check if a function has been passed. which also allows to use it like so `not(bigger(1,2))`:

```
 function not(anything){
  if (typeof anything != "function"){return !anything } 
   return function (...arguments) {
      return !anything.apply(null,arguments)
   }
 }


var variable = true
console.log(not(bigger(6))) >>> true
console.log(not(variable))) >>> false
console.log(not(false))) >>> true
```

in short:

```
const not = f => typeof f != "function" ? !f : (...a) => !f.apply(null,a)
```